# Cut entire row based on cell color vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 500k row data. I have highlighted duplicated cells in A column using conditional formatting.

I want to write VBA code to check for highlighted cells in red color in column A and then cut and paste respective entire row to a new sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have in mind that when you remove one cell which it is colored due to duplication, the other cell which was also colored become non color if there are not other cells with the same value. Modify if needed and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim LastRowS1 As Long, LastRowS2 As Long, i As Long

    LastRowS1 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LastRowS1 To 2 Step -1

            If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 Then

                LastRowS2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Cut Sheet2.Range("A" & LastRowS2 + 1)

                Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

            End If

        Next i

End Sub
```